# Why am I getting a "cannot find symbol" error when creating an object?

Tags: java

When I'm trying to create a new object from a class I previously defined, I keep getting a "cannot find symbol" error, and there's an arrow pointing towards the "S" in the first "SnowFallReport" in my constructor. I've had this problem when trying to create other objects in other programs and I just wanna throw my laptop! I feel like it's a simple solution, I just don't know what it is.

The code follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SnowfallReport
{   

    // Random amount of snow
    private double snowAmount;

    // Default constructor creates random amount and assigns to snowAmount
    public void SnowFallReport()
    {
        Random snowFall = new Random();
        snowAmount = (snowFall.nextDouble()) * 20;
    }

    public double getSnow()
    {
        return snowAmount;
    }

    public void getStars()
    {
        for (int starAmount = 0; starAmount == snowAmount; starAmount++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        **SnowFallReport day1 = new SnowFallReport();**
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual output from the compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java is case sensitive language` **SnowfallReport != SnowFallReport**

your class name is `SnowfallReport` thus you create your object like:

```
SnowfallReport  ref = new SnowfallReport ();
```

also, constructor name should be the same as class name and they  don't have return type not even void.

```
// Default constructor creates random amount and assigns to snowAmount
    public void SnowFallReport()
    {
```

should be

```
 public SnowfallReport()
        {
```

Comment: oh wow I could kiss you, thank you so much! Man I knew it was gonna be something simple lol